# Unable to show password prompt for AutoFill password in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, password-protection, apple-app-site-associate

[AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: "com.example.*" due to error: Cannot save passwords for this app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings

Comment: Have you set up the associated domains?  Is "com.example.*" the actual domain you are trying to use or have you just changed it for the question?

Comment: My domain is different and this "com.example" app Bundle iD for the app. I m getting above error and I added associated domain in app, but still throw an error